# Highlighting by color to the searched text in the highlighting results

Tags: solr

I am using highlighting to display the snippets. In the snippet result i want to highlight the searched text in different color like how we can get it in other tools like notepad++, word etc so that it will be properly visible in the result.
The reult which i get will be like -
        '.... [em] stackoverfolw [em/] ....'

now i want to highlight stackoverflow with some color or else just change the font color of the stackoverflow in the snippet. Is that possible? Please give the details in brief. I am new to solr.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While highlighting, Solr supports simple html style tags. Pass your html tags while querying.

```
hl.simple.pre=<font color="red">
hl.simple.post=</font>
```

When you'll render your result in html page, you'll see you highlighted data in "red" color. Try more styling and check.

Comment: While buddy is correct, I would use `<span class="highlighting">` and `</span>`. That way you may change the highlighting via CSS instead of configuring solr.

Comment: Buddy86, No! not working. I even changed in the solrconfig.xml. Still it dint work. I usually keep in json mode in solr admin page. i tried with xml also. but colors never appear. instead, <font color="red" appears instead of <em>

Comment: and is it possible to change the color of the result which will be displayed in the admin page? Thanks in advance

Comment: vidz please don't expect the color or font to be appeared in the Solr Admin page. I've mentioned that they will appear when you render the response to some html page

Comment: ok. Buddy86, do you have any idea why by default solr/browse doesn't work? I am using solr4.6.0. I have also followed the site https://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter.
But not able to load that page. Can you please help me in this.. Thanks in advance